# NASM Segmentation Fault upon Return

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

Was wondering if anybody can clear up a little problem I am having with NASM assembler; I'm rather new at it so don't know a lot of the principles..

Anyways, I call up a function, concatenate, it pushes the register rcx onto the stack, performs concatenation code, then pushes rcx off of the stack. It's after this point when it gets the the `ret` statement that it gets a segmentation fault.

This is what my call looks like:

```
mov eax, first ;first operand
mov ebx, second ;second operand
mov ecx, result 
call concatenate
```

What I believe to be happening inside the function call is it somehow pops off the return address from the stack? I'm not sure why this would happen, but again, that's why I'm here.

My function:

```
con:
push rcx ;just pushes one register right now to test
;code is here, nothing related to sp
pop rcx
ret
```

If anyone can clear this up for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Likely you overwrite the stack due to addressing issue. Can't tell without seeing the code. You could put a memory write watch on the return address in your debugger and catch whoever is modifying it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use any debuggers yet because I'm just starting to learn assembler. As far as I can see in my code there is nothing that would overwrite the stack. Essentially I push rcx, perform comparisons/jumps/movs that are only using registers eax, ebx, and ecx. I don't touch esp at all, so I'm not sure how it would overwrite.

Comment: I figured out my error and it's really stupid haha, sorry for bugging you. I push rbx on from within a loop, so it actually gets pushed on more than once. So when I'm returning the program tries to return to the memory location of rbx.

Comment: So you did in fact modify `sp`